# .htaccess rewrite issue with no slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I've searched for awhile now and can't find a solution to my issue, maybe I'm just not searching for the right thing, but anyways, here's what's happening.

I have the following mod_rewrites in my .htaccess file. The rewrites work perfectly, but if I do NOT have the trailing slash, then it show's a variable automatically in the url. Please see the example below to get a clear understanding.

## URL Sample

If I enter `http://website.com/test/`, (notice the trailing slash) the page URL will stay the exact same and load the content perfectly!

BUT, if I forget the trailing slash, ie: `http://website.com/test`, then the page URL will change to `http://website.com/test/?var1=test`. (now notice I had left out the trailing slash to begin with) the content still loads properly and everything works perfectly fine, just my URL is "ugly" now.

I hope I made this clear, but if you have any questions, please feel free to ask. Thank you!

## .htaccess Code

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is not related to the part of `.htaccess` you are showing. None of the rules have simple `?var1=` redirect, only with `_client.php` in front and it is not in the final URL. Check rules in `.htaccess` of the site's root or rules in the config of the server.

Comment: I don't think I'm quite understanding. This .htaccess is in my root directory and below is the PHP I'm using to grab the variables.

       `<?php
       $clientURL = str_replace("/", "", $_REQUEST["var1"]);
       $seriesSet = str_replace("/", "", $_REQUEST["var2"]);
       $sermonSet = str_replace("/", "", $_REQUEST["var3"]);
       $serviceSet = str_replace("/", "", $_REQUEST["var4"]);
       ?>`

Comment: And what do you do next in `_client.php`? Can it make this redirection? I'm just writing that non of the rules have simple redirect to `?var1=...`, only with `_client.php` and `_client.php` is not in URL. Something happened, as I think, but in listed rules.

Comment: Does `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1 [L]` not tell what `var1` to do? After I set the PHP variables, I simply start pulling database values based off the variables. What sort of redirect would I need, in your opinion?

Comment: Try to add `DirectorySlash Off` directive to `.htaccess`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to `mod_dir` module that adds a trailing slash after your `mod_rewrite` rules have finished. Have your rules like this to avoid this problem:

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ _client.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```